# Getting error "Input string was not in a correct format." in SelectParameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Query:

```
SELECT [VehicleId], [VehicleNumber], [VehicleBrand], [VehicleName], [ModelYear], [PurchasePrice]
FROM [VehicleMaster]
WHERE ([VehicleType]=@VehicleType or @VehicleType = '') and 
    ([VehicleNumber]=@VehicleNumber or @VehicleNumber is null) and 
    ([SaleStatus] = @SaleStatus or @SaleStatus = '-Select-') and 
    ([OwnershipStatus]=@OwnershipDetail or @OwnershipDetail = '-Select-')  and
    ([ModelYear] between @YearFrom and @YearTo or (@YearFrom = 'Year' and @YearTo = 'Year'))
```

Markup:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="VehicleType" SessionField="VehicleType" Type="String" />
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="VehicleNumber" SessionField="VehicleNumber" Type="String" />
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="SaleStatus" SessionField="SalesStatus" Type="String" />
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="OwnershipDetail" SessionField="OwnershipStatus" Type="String" />
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="YearFrom" SessionField="YearFrom" Type="Int32"  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="YearTo" SessionField="YearTo" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.e....

Comment: Please show us your surrounding code.. this is a mess at the moment.

Comment: "False"> Blockquote? what kind of condition this is?

Comment: It looks like there are misplaced "blockquote" tags in your server side code... maybe hit the wrong button in the HTML-Format toolbar once?

Comment: You are declaring `@YearFrom` and `@YearTo` to be Int32's but compare them against 'Year' - which isn't a number.  - at least I glanced at that in the posted Query that got edited away :)

Comment: wow.., what happend to the query in the question? Now its parameters??

Comment: i just comapre that value to database modelyear like...

Comment: are you getting vehicle type from query, I think you are returning vehicle Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(@YearFrom = 'Year' and @YearTo = 'Year')
```

would imply that the varaibles `@YearFrom` and `@YearTo` are strings, but you declare them as Int32

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="YearFrom" SessionField="YearFrom" Type="Int32"  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
<asp:SessionParameter Name="YearTo" SessionField="YearTo" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```

Which will fail during execution since the string 'Year' isn't an int type.

Comment: Did you change the 'Year' to something numeric or the Type of the parameter to "String"? It may also mean that the Session Field "Year From" has a non-integer. The Error message indicates that some string parsing went wrong. Hard to tell just about where without the complete stack trace...